# Install windows 98 on my PC

Tags: hardware-failure, windows-installation, windows-98

I want to install windows 98 on my PC. But it says that windows 98 is supported by the system. Here are the specifications of the PC

Processor - Core 2 Quad 6600
Mother Board Chip set - G 41
Ram - 4 GB DDR3
VGA - Asus 4850

How I install Windows 98 on this PC. Which hardware is the incompatible on with Win 98?

Comment: Consider a virtual machine.

Comment: Are you using a window OEM install disk, not a retail disk? An installation disk for say Dell or HP would give an error msg something like that if you tried to install it on a non-Dell or HP machine.

Comment: Most likely a 64bit machine and Win98 doesn't support that architecture.

Answer (score 2):

Install virtual machine (for example [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)) in your OS.
Then install Win98 into the virtual machine and run the Win98 in virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 98 is from long time out of support. So you (with very high probability) will not find drivers for motherboard, videocontroller, network.

Think about install Windows 7 or 8. Or some linux distribution